# What is the wrong with SQL multi queries in mysqli_query()

Tags: php, mysqli

This is the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ('2630','latit' at line 216772

Here is the code

```
$q = mysqli_query($connection ,"insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ('$last_id','longitude','30');
                                insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ('$last_id','latitude','30');
                                insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ('$last_id','tagline','doctor');
                                insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ('$last_id','verify_user','on');
                                insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ('$last_id','contact_form','off');
                                insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ('$last_id','first_name','$doctor_name');
                                insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ('$last_id','address','$address');
                                insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ('$last_id','phone_number','$mobile');
                                insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ('$last_id','nickname','$doctor_name');
                                insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ('$last_id','user_type','professional');
                                insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ('$last_id','profile_status','active');
                                insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ('$last_id','directory_type','127');
                                insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ('$last_id','user_profile_specialist','$specialicity');
                                insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ('$last_id','$specialicity','$specialicity')                  
    ");
```

I can't find any problem at the query

Answer (score -1):

You can use `msqli_multi_query` for this. We will concatenate each of the sql statement.

```
$query = "first statement;";
$query .= "second statement;";
$query .= "third statement;";
$query .= "last statement";
```

Then to execute these query statements, you will do something like this:

```
if(mysqli_multi_query($connection, $query)) {
   echo "New records created successfully";
} 
else {
   echo "Error: " . $query. "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection);
}
```

Comment: i tried this solve but it give me this error: 
Commands out of sync; you can't run this command nowCommands out of sync; you can't run this command now16773

Comment: get me this error
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_store_results()

Comment: @احمدحمادة Wrong of me. It should be `if($result = msqli_store_results($connection))`. Now, that will work.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function msqli_store_results()

Comment: @احمدحمادة Typo error, it seems. I edited my answer, i just removed **'s'** in msqli_store_results(). Should be msqli_store_result() only.

Comment: function msqli_results() not found.
then ..try mysqli_free_result() 
Warning: mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,

Comment: @احمدحمادة Can you try now my updated answer. It seems that the solution I gave you last time was not applicable since that was for sql statement for fetching data such as SELECT.

Comment: after alot of search 
I found this simple query to collect all this queries together

insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES 
 ('$last_id','longitude','29'),
 ('$last_id','latitude','29'),
 ('$last_id','tagline','doctor'),
.........
thank you for tring to help me

Comment: Glad you found your answer to your own problem. If that solved your case,then you should answer your question so that others can see.

Answer (score -2):

try putting ; after the last insert statement:

.... insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ('$last_id','$specialicity','$specialicity') ;

Answer (score -2):

`userId` must be numeric and you are passing a string.

Try this:

```
$q = mysqli_query($connection ,"insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ($last_id,'longitude','30');
    insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ($last_id,'latitude','30');
    insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ($last_id,'tagline','doctor');
    insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ($last_id,'verify_user','on');
    insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ($last_id,'contact_form','off');
    insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ($last_id,'first_name','$doctor_name');
    insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ($last_id,'address','$address');
    insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ($last_id,'phone_number','$mobile');
    insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ($last_id,'nickname','$doctor_name');
    insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ($last_id,'user_type','professional');
    insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ($last_id,'profile_status','active');
    insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ($last_id,'directory_type','127');
    insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ($last_id,'user_profile_specialist','$specialicity');
    insert into wp_abzj_usermeta (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ($last_id,'$specialicity','$specialicity')                  
");
```

Check as well any variable you are passing with quotes.